# Unable to use Elixir after upgrade

Tags: laravel, laravel-elixir

I upgraded my Elixir version from 3.0 to 5.0. The **npm update** command runs fine but when I try to run **gulp --production** it fails.

I have given the error below which I get.

My package.json file (which should be identical to the one at https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/package.json)

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
  "prod": "gulp --production",
  "dev": "gulp watch"
  },

 "devDependencies": {
 "gulp": "^3.9.1",
 "laravel-elixir": "^5.0.0",
 "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.0"
  }
}
```

When running gulp --production I get the below error

```
/home/vagrant/Code/laravel/node_modules/laravel-  elixir/node_modules/gulp- cssnano/node_modules/cssnano/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:157
    this.processing = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                          ^
ReferenceError: Promise is not defined
at LazyResult.async (/home/vagrant/Code/laravel/node_modules/laravel-elixir/node_modules/gulp-cssnano/node_modules/cssnano/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:157:31)
at LazyResult.then (/home/vagrant/Code/laravel/node_modules/laravel-elixir/node_modules/gulp-cssnano/node_modules/cssnano/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:79:21)
at Transform.stream._transform (/home/vagrant/Code/laravel/node_modules/laravel-elixir/node_modules/gulp-cssnano/index.js:27:17)
at Transform._read (_stream_transform.js:179:10)
at Transform._write (_stream_transform.js:167:12)
at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:226:10)
at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:216:5)
at Transform.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:183:11)
at write (/home/vagrant/Code/laravel/node_modules/laravel-elixir/node_modules/gulp-concat/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:623:24)
at flow (/home/vagrant/Code/laravel/node_modules/laravel-elixir/node_modules/gulp-concat/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:632:7)
```

Comment: Might have to update your version of Node also?

Comment: Yes. You are right now it works thanks

Comment: No worries. Glad it got working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to upgrade Node also.

You can read here how it can be updated upgraded: 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/426750/how-can-i-update-my-nodejs-to-the-latest-version